# Very poor OpenVPN performance on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: vpn, pi-4, raspbian-buster

Recently I configured OpenVPN via PiVPN on my Raspberry Pi Model 4B with newest Raspbian Buster (4.19.58-v7l+) to have an access to my home network from anywhere. Since beginning I have a very poor Downlink/Uplink badnwidth which can be measured in B/s. I'm unable to visit my favourite websites not to mention private cloud access or video streaming. Normally when I'm connected directly to my network I can get ~60Mbps D and ~30Mbps U. I'm using Huawei B618 4G LTE router and my IPS is Orange Polska S.A. Configuration is based on this tutorial so it's very basic. Here what it's looks like in /etc/openvpn/server.conf

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 6482
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/server_HlKPhGMmp1IxJs0k.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/server_HlKPhGMmp1IxJs0k.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
# Set your primary domain name server address for clients
# Prevent DNS leaks on Windows
push "block-outside-dns"
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
#DuplicateCNs allow access control on a less-granular, per user basis.
#Remove # if you will manage access by user instead of device.
#duplicate-cn
# Generated for use by PiVPN.io
```

For now I've tried setting up sndbuf and rcvbuf to various values and changing DNS server to 8.8.8.8 but without any results. As a DNS i'm using PiHole server also configured on my Raspberry.

Have you guys any idea what is configured wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Mariusz

Comment: *"to have an access to my home network from anywhere. Since beginning I have a very poor Downlink/Uplink badnwidth which can be measured in B/s. I'm unable to visit my favourite websites not to mention private cloud access or video streaming"* -> From where is the bandwidth bad?  If your goal is simply to access stuff at home remotely, you don't need to tunnel any internet **unless** you have some additional goal that requires that, e.g. PiHole... Put another way, don't use the VPN for DNS or WWW access unless there are no other choices.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of your bandwith-limitations?

30Mbps = 3.75 MB/s

That means your piVPN may only provide that speed as download to your devices. Then add encryption processes, latency and poor mobile connections and you are nearly done.

I would recommend to first do some speed-checks e.g. on speedtest.net and check out different conditions on different devices. That will help you to optimize your system.